# Where to ppp username and password to initiate a PPP session?

Tags: linux, ppp

I am using RedHat Linux 5.4 and I would like know where should I update the PPP username and password sothat I can connect to the ISP?

Comment: "I am using RedHat Linux" No you're not. Be accurate.

Comment: Well, if he's using something sufficiently out of date, that *could* be correct. But I certainly hope it isn't!

Comment: I am using ReaHat 5.4

Comment: Sure you're not using CentOS 5.4?

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party but I'm sure this will help someone.

You can do this in NetworkManager UI. You can open it by right clicking the network icon in your taskbar or running the following command:

```
nm-connection-editor &
```

No screen? No problem. To do it via the command line, make a new PPP connection:

```
sudo nmcli connection edit con-name "My new PPP connection"
```

First, it'll ask you for a type. I'm going to assume you're looking for PPPoE here:

```
Valid connection types: generic, 802-3-ethernet (ethernet), pppoe, 802-11-wireless (wifi), wimax, gsm, cdma, infiniband, adsl, bluetooth, vpn, 802-11-olpc-mesh (olpc-mesh), vlan, bond, team, bridge, bond-slave, team-slave, bridge-slave
Enter connection type: pppoe
```

You're now editing a new connection. Type `help` for a list of commands. Type `print` to show the current configuration.

```
nmcli> print
...
```

For PPPoE, your username and password go in the `pppoe.username` and `pppoe.password` properties.

```
nmcli> set pppoe.username <username>
nmcli> set pppoe.password <password>
```

Save

```
nmcli> save
nmcli> quit
```

Now connect with

```
sudo nmcli connection up "My new PPP connection" ifname <interface name>
```